# Vertical Seek in file for data using C

Tags: c, file, seek

I have a file containing the data(of signed numbers) arranged as follows:

```
   291
 -1332
   912
   915
 -1347
   196
  1110
  -997
   120
  1017
  -775
  -443
   985
    13
  -690
   369
   673
  -826
   -14
   891
  -546...(thousands of lines)
```

I want to use a function which will move my file pointer to particular number of line for ex.1100

currently I am using following code to skip and go to particular line/number

```
if (offset>0)//offset is number of destination line
{
 while(fscanf(f,"%d",&buffer)!=EOF) //f is file pointer ;Buffer is int variable
   { 
    i++;
    if(i==offset)
            break;
    }

}
```

I want to use better code than this as this code takes more time as offset increases, 
Any ideas to implement this in easy way ( and for shorter time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your numbers are (for example) six characters in length, and you have a single `\n` newline character at the end of each line, you can get to line number `n` (zero-based) by fseeking to `n * 7`. Line 0 is at offset 0, line 1 at offset 7, line 2 at offset 14 and so on.

Similarly, line 1100 (the 1101st line), could be gotten to with something like:

```
if (fseek (f, 7700L, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
    // something went wrong.
}
if (fscanf (f, "%d", &buffer) != 1) {
    // something else went wrong.
}
```

That will work for *any* fixed width line, you just have to adjust the multiplication factor based on the line width and the line endings (for example, DOS encoding may have *two* characters, `\r\n`).

Of course, you may find it advantageous to just read the entire file into an integer array in memory (depending on *how* many thousands there are) so that random access to the data becomes blindingly fast - that's because there's no reason to go back to the file for any data after the initial load.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options. If you ***have to*** keep a text file of numbers, and since each line is a variable length, you could:

- mmap (memory map) the contents of the file and index the line numbers to an array.  For this you would need to make a single pass of the file and generate an array of file offsets where each line begins.
- Re-write the file as binary data (array of ints, for example) - it is more compact and faster to seek since each integer is found at nth_int * sizeof(int).  You pay the penalty once at the beginning to re-write the file.
- Much depends on your environment and use cases and that's where your better judgement rules.  Above all, test and measure to see if its worth it.

Comment: What's the point in using a DSP if you are doing so many i/o ops that it slows you down?  Ideally, you should get what you need to work with in memory so that you are utilzing your DSP 100%, no?